# Is there a way to edit styles of span in an option in React Select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

I just wanna know, if there is a way to change the span's font size. How can we refer to it?

```
import React from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: I need to change the span below: <br><span>Hi, I am going to be a little be smaller</span> },
]

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Select options={options} />
)
```

Comment: you can create a custom `Option` using `components` system provided by `react-select`. [Docs](https://react-select.com/components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  {
    value: 'chocolate',
    label: (
      <>
        I need to change the span below:
        <br />
        <span style={{ fontSize: '0.8em' }}>
          Hi, I am going to be a little bit smaller
        </span>
      </>
    ),
  },
];

const formatLabel = ({ label }) => <>{label}</>;

const MyComponent = () => <Select options={options} formatOptionLabel={formatLabel}/>;
```

##### formatOptionLabel

Formats option labels in the menu and control as React components

`(...) => ...`

##### References

[react-select docs](https://react-select.com/props)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a `style` attribute to the span tag and set the font size you want in there.

You can explore more ways to style react-select elements in the docs: https://react-select.com/styles